# Pick from image library button on toolbar gets deactivated

Tags: ios, swift, uiimagepickercontroller

I have a simple iOS app that lets me pick an image by pressing a Bar Button Item on the UIToolbar. The issue is that it lets me pick the image for the first time however it gets deactivated afterwards. I am unable to pick any images later. Please note the exact same code works perfectly when I use a UIButton instead of the button on my toolbar. Can somebody please help, I seem to be stuck ?

The logic for picking image ->

```
@IBAction func pickImage(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    print("Picker")
    let controller = UIImagePickerController()
    controller.delegate = self
    if sender.tag == 1 {
         controller.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.Camera
    } else {
        controller.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.PhotoLibrary
    }

    self.presentViewController(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)

}
```

Handling the picked image and setting it in my image view ->

```
func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject]) {

    if let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage{
        memeImageView.image = image
    }
    dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}

func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(picker: UIImagePickerController) {
    print("On cancel")
    dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}
```

[image: Gallery button gets deactivated after selecting once]

Comment: Does this line being called after first time? `memeImageView.image = image`

Comment: Yes that is how the image got loaded as shown in the GIF. Once the image was selected during the first time, after that the function "pickImage" was never invoked even when I tried to click the Gallery button.

Comment: Can you show how you add the button and toolbar? And you can inspect the UI layers to see whether there's anything on top of the button.

Comment: Is it possible that your sender `UIBarButtonItem`, gets disabled somewhere in the code?

Comment: @zcui93 I am adding the button and the tool bar using the Interface Builder and not programatically. Could you tell me how can I inspect the UI layers ?

UditS I do not think so, I am not doing that at all

Comment: @zcui93 The difference within my view hierarchies before adding the image (when the button was working) and after adding it (when the button wont work) are [here](https://www.diffchecker.com/xnfbrqo6)
I couldn't make much sense out of it but I thought probably you could.

Comment: You can visualize the UI layers by clicking a double rectangle in the same toolbar, where you can debug 'pause' and 'step over'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the view hierarchy link provided, after image is set

> UIImageView: 0x7fdd90418e00; frame = (16 56; 343 **468**);

It seems that the image is longer than expected. And it covered the toolbar, which can also be explained why the toolbar is not shown (white) after image is selected.

Suggestions:

- Check the constraint for bottom space of the `ImageView`
- Not entirely sure why there's two `ImageView`s in your hierarchy

Comment: Spot on, also thanks for teaching me debugging the view hierarchy visually. Somehow I thought that the toolbar had the buttons embedded in it so if the toolbar would get hidden, so would the "Gallery" and "Camera" buttons. Didn't work like that though, I am a beginner :P